# Why does dmesg ring the terminal bell on unsuspend?

Tags: terminal

Whenever I unsuspend my laptop, the tmux window I have open (running `dmesg -w`) lights up:

[image: image of tmux status line, with one window highlighted]

From the tmux man page, this means that the application running in the window has rung the terminal bell.

I have another machine with essentially the same setup (same operating system, same tmux config), and this doesn't happen there – only on this specific laptop. Why is dmesg ringing the terminal bell on unsuspend on this machine?

Software versions:

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Mon Jan 8 23:08:08 PST 2018 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -cr
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
$ tmux -V
tmux 2.6
$ dmesg --version
dmesg from util-linux 2.27.1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you examine dmesg's output, you can see exactly when it's ringing the bell, by grepping for the ASCII BEL character `\a`:

```
$ dmesg | grep -C1 $'\a'
[    5.706427] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HD WebCam
[    5.706434] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: NC2141103Q533020AALM03
[    5.798439] Unsafe core_pattern used with suid_dumpable=2. Pipe handler or fully qualified core dump path required.
--
[13843.531106] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HD WebCam
[13843.531115] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: NC2141103Q533020AALM03
[13843.546586] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HD WebCam (0bda:57cf)
```

Interestingly, the bell-ringing appears to be happening halfway through initialising the webcam. We can check exactly where in the line the BEL is being printed by piping through od:

```
$ dmesg | grep $'\a' | head -n 1 | od -c
0000000   [                   5   .   7   0   6   4   3   4   ]       u
0000020   s   b       1   -   2   :       S   e   r   i   a   l   N   u
0000040   m   b   e   r   :      \a   N   C   2   1   4   1   1   0   3
0000060   Q   5   3   3   0   2   0   A   A   L   M   0   3  \n
0000076
```

The BEL is represented here as `\a`, and it's being printed just before the serial number (`SerialNumber: ␇NC214...`). It seems unlikely that dmesg would insert a BEL halfway through a line, so maybe it's the kernel that's logging it.

Let's check the source code. Maybe the USB driver is printing a bell when it logs the serial number. We can use [livegrep](https://livegrep.com/search/linux?q=new%20usb%20device%20strings&fold_case=auto&regex=false&context=true) to quickly search the Linux 4.12 source, and find that the relevant file is likely to be `drivers/usb/core/hub.c`. Then, we can go back to the Linux 3.10.18 source by using [Elixir](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.10.18/source/drivers/usb/core/hub.c#L2102), and find the relevant function:

```c
static void announce_device(struct usb_device *udev)
{
    dev_info(&udev->dev, "New USB device found, idVendor=%04x, idProduct=%04x\n",
        le16_to_cpu(udev->descriptor.idVendor),
        le16_to_cpu(udev->descriptor.idProduct));
    dev_info(&udev->dev,
        "New USB device strings: Mfr=%d, Product=%d, SerialNumber=%d\n",
        udev->descriptor.iManufacturer,
        udev->descriptor.iProduct,
        udev->descriptor.iSerialNumber);
    show_string(udev, "Product", udev->product);
    show_string(udev, "Manufacturer", udev->manufacturer);
    show_string(udev, "SerialNumber", udev->serial);
}
```

`show_string` is a very simple function, defined just above `announce_device`, that pretty much just prints its arguments separated by a colon and a space:

```c
static void show_string(struct usb_device *udev, char *id, char *string)
{
    if (!string)
        return;
    dev_info(&udev->dev, "%s: %s\n", id, string);
}
```

So it's not the kernel that's adding the bell either.

What's the USB device's serial number?

We can check with lsusb:

```
$ lsusb -vd 0bda:57cf | grep iSerial
  iSerial                 2 NC2141103Q533020AALM03
```

OK, now let's pipe it through od:

```
$ lsusb -vd 0bda:57cf | grep iSerial | od -c
0000000           i   S   e   r   i   a   l
0000020                                           2      \a   N   C   2
0000040   1   4   1   1   0   3   Q   5   3   3   0   2   0   A   A   L
0000060   M   0   3  \n
0000064
```

which suggests that, in fact, the webcam's serial number contains an ASCII BEL.

Comment: To which the next obvious question is: _why_ does the serial number contain `BEL`? One would expect such an identifier to be either numeric or composed entirely of printable characters